# Data missing when importing a spreadsheet into InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am currently having a bit of a delima importing excel spreadsheets into InDesign.

The spreadsheets in question use formulas to pull data from other spreadsheets on the network (using vlookup) - currently set as, Part Number (Alpha-numeric, Description (Paragraph), case qty. (number), Price (currency).

When importing the spreadsheet (using File > Import), it imports everything correctly, including the headers; except for the description paragraphs.

I am currently using ID5.5 and the spreadsheets are .xlsx

Is it a bug with InDesign? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing several tests, I had a hunch that ID5.5 might not be compatible with new excel files (with the .xlsx extension). So I saved my excel spreadsheets with the earlier 2007-2013 version (.xls), and long and behold, it imported the data as desired.
I hope that this little tip might help someone who might be having a similar issue.
TIP OF THE DAY: Always check for software/document compatibility.

Comment: This problem still persists, even in CC 2018, and I ran into an issue with .xls files, they are A LOT bigger than .xlxs (mine was like 22 mb instead of 2 mb) and was REALY slow importing. While .xlxs was really fast (and i had many sheets). I mean, .xlxs is now standard for Excel so ideally Adobe should make this work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Select "Place" from the File menu. Select "Import Options" and double-click the Excel file containing your spreadsheet. The Import Options dialog box opens. Click the "Sheet" menu and select the worksheet from the Excel workbook that you want to import

Comment: The issue is not how to import it, but rather that I'm importing a spreadsheet with formulas in them. If the formula results in a number, the number is imported, but if it text, the cell will be blank. This is where I have the problem.

Comment: Right, but importing a document is essentially like embedding it. Placing the file makes it a linked object which can be subject any live modifications. The threads I read through used 'place' instead of 'import'.

Sorry I couldn't be more help. Good luck.